# Visual Studio 2013 and Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, edmx, edmx-designer

I'm working on an older project that uses Entity Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2013. When going to "Update Model from Database" it only gives me EF 5 or EF 6 to choose from when updating the database. This installs EF 5 in my project and upgrades it from EF4 to EF5.

I attempted converting the project to EF5, but entity framework has a bug where classes in different name spaces cannot have the same class name in the entity model. This would require a WHOLE LOT of changes.

Reading about EF 6, they said this bug was resolved, but it was only resolved for code first EF. This doesn't work for us.

All I want is to update the EF4 .emdx and add a table in visual studio 2013 using the designer.

HELP!

Comment: Did the entity framework ever support that? I thought they only introduced duplicate entity class names in EF6 code first.

Comment: Yes in EF4, but not EF4.5: [Read Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114558/ef4-3-1-on-net-4-the-mapping-of-clr-type-to-edm-type-is-ambiguous-because-mul/13772969#13772969)

Comment: hmm... Well install ef4 from nuget?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Use Entity Framework 4 with Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19923156/how-to-use-entity-framework-4-with-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: I installed EF4 and tried the above link. It's already set to legacy object context. The problem is the radio list when updating the model doesn't list EF4, only EF6 and EF5 even after installing EF4.

Comment: This sucks. I would file a ticket with MSFT